# Regular Expression not working as expected in Snoflake python connector

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task, snowsql

I have written a query which will filter out all the phone_no that is not of pattern **(nnn)-nnn-nnnnn**.

```
select * 
from employee
where  not RLIKE(phone_no,'^\\(\\d{3}\\)-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$');
```

It is giving the result as expected when I am query directly in **Snowflake Console**.
But when i am using `snowflake-connector-python` to run the same query using `python`it is not working as expected.

```py
        query="""
                INSERT  into   DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE_INTER_ATIF
                select * , 'Phone_No::Invalid Number'
                from DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.employee
                where  NOT  RLIKE(phone_no,'^\\(\\d{3}\\)-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$');
        """
        cs.execute(query).
```

CS is the name of the cursor that I have made.

What is the issue here.

Comment: Try making the double slashes into single slashes, I am not sure you need to escape slashes in this context?

Comment: @LornaMitchell ,I did that too, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that Python is interpreting special characters (like backslashes) within your string literal (the text inside your triple-quotes) **before** the string is being presented to Snowflake. To instruct Python NOT to do this, prefix the opening triple-quote with `r`, as follows:

```
query=r"""
INSERT  into   DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE_INTER_ATIF
select * , 'Phone_No::Invalid Number'
from DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.employee
where  NOT  RLIKE(phone_no,'^\\(\\d{3}\\)-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$');
"""
```

You can easily see the difference if you write a trivial Python script like this and execute it:

```
query="""
INSERT  into   DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE_INTER_ATIF
select * , 'Phone_No::Invalid Number'
from DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.employee
where  NOT  RLIKE(phone_no,'^\\(\\d{3}\\)-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$');
"""
print(query)
query=r"""
INSERT  into   DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE_INTER_ATIF
select * , 'Phone_No::Invalid Number'
from DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.employee
where  NOT  RLIKE(phone_no,'^\\(\\d{3}\\)-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$');
"""
print(query)
```

The output is:

```
INSERT  into   DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE_INTER_ATIF
select * , 'Phone_No::Invalid Number'
from DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.employee
where  NOT  RLIKE(phone_no,'^\(\d{3}\)-\d{3}-\d{4}$');


INSERT  into   DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE_INTER_ATIF
select * , 'Phone_No::Invalid Number'
from DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.employee
where  NOT  RLIKE(phone_no,'^\\(\\d{3}\\)-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$');
```

Comment: Yeah ,I managed to fix the issue by printing ,I was able to see that it was eating up a slash , so i added one more slash and it started working